How to calculate day difference with specified conditions between rows in pyspark
I am a beginner of Pyspark.
I have a dataframe like below and want to calculate the day difference between the "first date" of "Type D" and "last date" of the PREVIOUS row of "Type I" within the same ID.
May I know how I can achieve this with Pyspark codes?
If difficult, pandas is also appreciated.
My dataframe

Expected result

Thanks in advance.

Do I understand correctly that you need it within groups with the same ID's and sorted by first_date column?

Thanks! Your understanding is correct.

from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    ('A2A', 'I', date(2023, 4, 1), date(2023, 4, 5)),
    ('A2A', 'D', date(2023, 4, 5), date(2023, 4, 7)),
    ('A2A', 'D', date(2023, 5, 10), date(2023, 5, 13)),
    ('BB3', 'I', date(2023, 5, 5), date(2023, 5, 6)),
    ('BB3', 'I', date(2023, 7, 29), date(2023, 8, 2)),
    ('BB3', 'D', date(2023, 9, 30), date(2023, 10, 3))
],
('ID', 'Type', 'first_date', 'last_date'))
df.show()

# +---+----+----------+----------+
# | ID|Type|first_date| last_date|
# +---+----+----------+----------+
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|
# |A2A|   D|2023-04-05|2023-04-07|
# |A2A|   D|2023-05-10|2023-05-13|
# |BB3|   I|2023-05-05|2023-05-06|
# |BB3|   I|2023-07-29|2023-08-02|
# |BB3|   D|2023-09-30|2023-10-03|
# +---+----+----------+----------+

Now we need to break the df down into 2 dfs to separate types I and D
df_l = df.filter(F.col('Type') == 'I')
df_r = df.filter(F.col('Type') == 'D')

# the next 2 rows are to avoid a known issue with joining dataframes derived from the same one.

df_l = df_l.toDF(*df_l.columns)
df_r = df_r.toDF(*df_r.columns)

Now we join these 2 dataframes to be able to make that subtraction of dates.
df_int = df_l.join(df_r, (df_l['ID'] == df_r['ID']) & (df_l['last_date'] <= df_r['first_date']), 'inner')
df_int.show()

# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+
# | ID|Type|first_date| last_date| ID|Type|first_date| last_date|
# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+
# |BB3|   I|2023-07-29|2023-08-02|BB3|   D|2023-09-30|2023-10-03|
# |BB3|   I|2023-05-05|2023-05-06|BB3|   D|2023-09-30|2023-10-03|
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|A2A|   D|2023-04-05|2023-04-07|
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|A2A|   D|2023-05-10|2023-05-13|
# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+

# Now filter out rows with preceding unnecessary 'I' entries
w = Window.partitionBy(df_l['ID'], df_r['first_date'], df_r['last_date']).orderBy(df_l['first_date'].desc(), df_l['last_date'].desc())
df_int = df_int.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w))
df_int = df_int.filter(F.col('rn') == 1).drop(F.col('rn'))
df_int.show()

# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+
# | ID|Type|first_date| last_date| ID|Type|first_date| last_date|
# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+
# |BB3|   I|2023-07-29|2023-08-02|BB3|   D|2023-09-30|2023-10-03|
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|A2A|   D|2023-04-05|2023-04-07|
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|A2A|   D|2023-05-10|2023-05-13|
# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+

# Adding date difference
f_int = df_int.withColumn('days_between', F.datediff(df_r['first_date'], df_l['last_date']))
df_int.show()

# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+------------+
# | ID|Type|first_date| last_date| ID|Type|first_date| last_date|days_between|
# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+------------+
# |BB3|   I|2023-07-29|2023-08-02|BB3|   D|2023-09-30|2023-10-03|          59|
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|A2A|   D|2023-04-05|2023-04-07|           0|
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|A2A|   D|2023-05-10|2023-05-13|          35|
# +---+----+----------+----------+---+----+----------+----------+------------+

# getting rid of unnecessary columns
df_int = df_int.select(df_l['ID'], df_r['Type'], df_r['first_date'], df_r['last_date'], F.col('days_between'))

Now we need to merge this information back to our original dataframe. We will make left join on a complex key consisting of ID, Type, first_date, last_date assuming that (first_date, last_date) pairs are unique.
df_res = df.join(df_int, ['ID', 'Type', 'first_date', 'last_date'], 'left').orderBy('ID', 'first_date')
df_res.show()

# +---+----+----------+----------+------------+
# | ID|Type|first_date| last_date|days_between|
# +---+----+----------+----------+------------+
# |A2A|   I|2023-04-01|2023-04-05|        null|
# |A2A|   D|2023-04-05|2023-04-07|           0|
# |A2A|   D|2023-05-10|2023-05-13|          35|
# |BB3|   I|2023-05-05|2023-05-06|        null|
# |BB3|   I|2023-07-29|2023-08-02|        null|
# |BB3|   D|2023-09-30|2023-10-03|          59|
# +---+----+----------+----------+------------+

